# Excel - Using INDEX MATCH MATCH with a diagonal range/array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use `INDEX MATCH MATCH` with a diagonal range of headers.

So I can return the value at `B5` (when I realised that `INDEX` actually refers to the cell in the order `ROW,COLUMN` (`5B`) instead of `COLUMN,ROW` (`B5`) using:

`=INDEX(A1:E5,MATCH(C8,A1:A5,0),MATCH(B8,A1:E1,0))`

This returns the value at `B5` (5,2) by matching the row with the value at `C8` (5) and the column with the value at `B8` (2) - and this works, see cell `B10`.

But when I replace the ranges `A1:A5` and `A1:E1` with `(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5)`:

`=INDEX(A1:E5,MATCH(C8,(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5),0),MATCH(B8,(A1,B2,C3,D4,E5),0))`

It returns `#N/A` (see cell `B9`)

Am I expecting too much to be able to use an array of non-contiguous cells in this manner?  Or should I be referencing them in a different way?

As a side note, the reason I am not converting the diagonal to a header row and column is that I would have to do it to 10s of tables that will end up as my source data, which are exported from other software.  These tables change frequently and adjusting them every time would take too much time.

[image: Excel screenshot - Normal Range]
[image: Excel screenshot - Diagonal Range]

**===========================================================================**

**EDIT**

New images to hopefully better display what I am trying to achieve.

So in these images, the formula gets the data from cells `J4` (Sheffield) and `J3` (Leeds) to return the data held where they intersect at `D6` (36).

`MATCH` tells `INDEX` where to find the `ROW` and `COLUMN`  of the selected area, and hopefully the formula returns the `CELL` at the intersection of `ROW` and `COLUMN`.

This works when the ranges are a "normal" header row and column, but it is falling down when I try to use a diagonal range.  I was hoping that it would simply count through the individual cells in the selected range.  I.e. "Sheffield" appears in the 5th cell in the range (`G6`), and "Leeds" is in the 2nd cell in the range (`D3`).  This, in my mind should then return the values `5,2` to the `INDEX` function and return the value stored in the 5th row and 2nd column of the selected area (`C2:H7`).

I hope this clarifies things.

[image: Excel screenshot - Normal Range (Revised)]
[image: Excel screenshot - Diagonal Range (Revised)]

Comment: Build the cell address you need based on source row/column numbers using INDIRECT() function with R1C1 notation (use concatenation to build proper address).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow.  Could you give an example?

Comment: `=INDIRECT("R" & C8 & "C" & B8, FALSE)`

Comment: And that helps how?  I'm sorry if I'm being dense - but I don't need the indirect to refer to the cells I'm matching when the data is in a standard row or column array, that works fine.  It's the array that in having issues with (I think - only just woken up and off to work)

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your task? I see you enter row number (5) to C8 and column number (2) to B8 for to obtain the value (1) of the cell.

Comment: Yes, but it needs to find those numbers in the diagonal array and then it will set the row and column based on the location of the numbers rather than the numbers themselves.  Maybe I've confused this by using numbers that directly correlate to the rows and columns.  Multiply all the numbers by 10 - I still want to get the result that is in ```B5``` but this time the numbers would be ```50, 20``` and the result ```10```

Comment: Please replace your example picture with one where the values differs as much as possible (optimum - no duplicated values at all).

Comment: I won't be able to do that for another 12 hours as I'm away from any PC while at work.

Comment: Nothing prevents to use Google Tables or any another worksheet service...

Comment: I drive buses, I get minutes at a terminus!  I'll do my best on my lunch break on my phone.  In the mean time, this may help.  This is what I'm doing, but instead of matching to a cell in a row or column, I want to match with the non-contiguous diagonal range as shown in my images.  https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/index-match-formula-excel/

Comment: @Escribblings,, your first formula in 2 way lookup and has valid logic if cell `E2` does have value, formula return it, since finds `2` in `A1:A5` and `5` in `A1:E1`. But second formula don't have any logic and both match trying to find value in `(A54,B55,C56,D57,E58)` !!

Comment: @Rajesh S - Thank you for the additional response.  Unfortunately this is the way my data is presented.  Think of a mileage chart in an atlas, you find your 2 locations on the diagonal and then where they're respective rows and columns intersect shows you the distance between the objects.  My data isn't a mileage chart, but the process is the same.  I have 30+ tables which are exported from other software and they only have the one "range" of "headers", which are on the diagonal.  In a normal table this data would be mirrored row for row and column for column as per image 1.

Comment: @Rajesh S - why have the cell values jumped from ```A1,B2,C3,D4,E5``` to ```A54,B55,C56,D57,E58``` in your response?

Comment: @Akina - I have managed to source a computer and login to my Office 365 account - I have created a 2nd example for you.  Hope this helps.

Comment: *it is falling down when I try to use a diagonal range* MATCH cannot accept non-vector (rectangle or multi-range) range as an argument.

Comment: OK, well in that case I am going to HAVE to create "helper" columns and rows in EVERY sheet!  Is there a quick way to copy/move the "Headers" without having to manually do each one?

Comment: Right, as far as the helper column is concerned, this might do the trick...  https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2100-excel-extract-diagonal-matrix.html - I'm away from the computers again, so I'll have to try this tonight.  But because the row and column headers are the same, I'll only need to create the one column to the right of the table and just reference it twice with the different data items.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am going to answer this myself.  It seems that what I want to do is simply just not possible with basic worksheet functions or creating helper columns.

So I was attempting to follow the tutorial for the `INDEX MATCH MATCH` formula here: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/index-match-formula-excel/ but Excel apparently will not allow me to reference a selection of individual, non-contiguous cells inside a `MATCH`.  So I am going to **have** to create a helper column.

Due to the way my table data is laid out, with the "headers" on the diagonal, I only need to create the 1 helper column to reference both the row **and** the column inside the `INDEX`.

I have found **TWO** ways of creating the said helper column.

Option 1 (shown in column `K`) extracts a diagonal matrix, following the tutorial here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2100-excel-extract-diagonal-matrix.html

The problem with this is that it relies on the required data to be in a perfect diagonal.

Option 2 (shown in column `J`) returns the data in the **last** non-blank cell in the row, following the instructions here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2104-excel-return-first-last-non-blank-cell-in-row-or-column.html

Matching the criteria against the helper column now returns the correct value.

[image: Excel screenshot - Helper formulae]

Comment: No need to use HELPER VALUES, since your both formula returns `36`,,, considering your screen shot position with OP above,, 1st formula should, `=INDEX(B2:H7,MATCH(J4,B2:B7,0),MATCH(J3,B2:H2,0))` and 2nd `=INDEX(C3:H7,MATCH(J4,B3:B7,0),MATCH(J3,C2:H2,0))` both gets value from cell `D6` !!

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding - could you change your response to reference the cells in the last screenshot in my "answer".  Also, of you believe it solves my problem, could you post it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Since I've tested with your data set shown as Screen shot with OP (with question above),, now you try both formula,, what I have suggested here, will return `36` !!

Comment: Ah - Ok, I'm seeing what you've done, but you've ignored the fact that I **don't** have straight header rows and columns, which is why I requested you use the data set in my "answer" rather than the OP.  The problem is the way my data is imported, I **do not** get a header row or column, the "headers" are staggered on the diagonal.  As in my "answer", so unless you can make my "answer" work without a helper column, I think you're missing what I'm trying to do. I apologise if the way I've explained it has not been clear enough.

Comment: You will also note that I successfully used that formula in the 3rd screenshot in the OP

Comment: I've used data all sets with OP & in all 4 the second formula using diagonal matrix returns "N/A" error,, that's what I was trying to say,, with your answer you have used HELPER data & the formula is working,, but I said No Need of Helper , simply try formula what I've suggested above (through comments) both are getting `36` !!

Comment: But no helper assumes at least a header row, or column, or both.  THESE DO NOT EXIST in the 30+ tables I'm extracting from 3rd party software.  I **only** have the diagonal.  Hence the need to use that, or, as I've found, create a helper.

Comment: You're also missing the point that I used "your" formula in my edit to the OP - see ```J6``` and ```K6``` - in those examples the header row and column are essentially helpers that I created to show the result I wanted from the diagonal.